# Why does the use of the array_merge method throw an error in this Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a blogging application in Laravel 8.

I have a `settings` table from which I pull the variables related to the site settings.

In the **FrontendController** I have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Settings;
class FrontendController extends Controller
{
    protected $theme_directory;
    protected $site_settings;
    public $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->theme_directory = Settings::first()->theme_directory ?? null;
        $this->site_settings = Settings::first();
    }
}
```

In the **ArticlesController** I pass the data after merging the *site settings* with the *articles*:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Article;
use App\Models\Settings;

class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

    public function index() {
        // All articles
        $articles = Article::all();
        $this->data = array_merge($this->site_settings, ['articles' => $articles]);
        return view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/index', $this->data);
    }
}
```

#### The problem

I get the error `array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given`.

##### NOTE

If I do `$this->data = array_merge([$this->site_settings], ['articles' => $articles])`, I get an `Undefined variable: site_name` error in `layout.blade.php`.

##### How do I fix this particular problem?

Comment: `array_merge(['site_settings' => $this->site_settings], ['articles' => $articles]);`. `array_merge` expects array, but `$this->site_settings` is not an array, it is an instance of your `Settings` model.

Comment: Also, if you're getting an error in your `layout.blade.php` file when trying to use `$site_name`, you'll need to include that code. With the change I suggested, it would be `$settings->site_name`

Comment: Or, if you wanted `$site_name` to be a variable, then `array_merge($this->site_settings->toArray(), ['articles' => $articles]);`; that would convert all properties of your `$this->site_settings` model instance to variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add square brackets to the first argument as site settings seems to be not an array.

Comment: I already did this, but the `$data` array becomes too nested and I can not use it in the Blade views. There should be a `site_name` variable in `site_settings` but I get an `Undefined variable: site_name` in `layout.blade.php`.

Comment: did you try also adding ['key' => settings]?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Provide more detais? Thanks!